# How to measure 120 Hz ripple current at the output of an LED driver?

Tags: current-measurement, led-driver, ripple-current

I have a 50W LED driver and a programmable load. Please suggest a way to measure 120Hz ripple current! I have an oscilloscope and multi-meters.

Comment: Set load to constant voltage. Hook up scope. Set scope to AC coupling. Measure the ripple.

Comment: A current shunt is easy but one has to know the voltages in use and currents expected and you have defined neither

Comment: winny defined how to measure ripple voltage which may be what you intended.

Comment: If you did want to measure the current (and not the voltage) do you have a current probe for your scope?

Comment: The best way is with a current probe. Second best way is a shunt with a differential probe. Sometimes you can use a ferrite bead or fuse as a shunt (if you know the resistance of it). You can also maybe use a current transformer, which is pretty similar to a current probe. If you are able to put the Ammeter in series with the current, you can measure with the multi-meter. But you won't be certain you are measuring 120 Hz. You won't be able to see the signal, so you won't really be sure what is going on.

Comment: Why do you want to measure 120 Hz ripple current? Are you in a country where line frequency is 60 Hz?

Comment: @winny - I was thinking of doing something on the same lines, but was curious if that will be enough to accurately determine ripple current.

Comment: @Tony Stewart, driver output is CC and is can vary from 20-54V DC. Output current max is 1400mA. Please help me understand what does it mean to have "Ripple current <2% at 120Hz".

Comment: @mkeith, yes line frequency is 60Hz. And I agree that using just a multi-meter, we can't know if it is 120Hz.

Comment: Depends on your eload.

Comment: "Ripple current <2% at 120Hz" means the power supply has decent regulation with input line induced load ripple from line bridge input to DC-DC converter that would not be visible. No need to measure it unless you have a specific application other than LED's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ripple current <2% at 120Hz" means the power supply has decent regulation with input line induced load ripple from line bridge input to DC-DC converter that would not be visible. No need to measure it unless you need to verify the spec.

If you used any reverse biased photo diode (PD) the voltage into a load R will show 2% FS ripple on the current with all other light sources turned off driven by 60Hz or blocked radiance to PD.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft2EFS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't have a PD, use any clear LED.

Comment: This is a good idea.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. Thanks for explaining. I think I found my answer as I was suspecting the same that, we can't really observe 120Hz ripple at the output of DC-DC converter, if it is doing it's job. And yes I am verifying a spec in this case. Thanks for your time in answering my question. Also perhaps there must be an easier measuring technique for output ripple by just observing the Output V using 1x probe with low-noise technique!